# If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials with some common roots, what is the polynomial whose roots are those common roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, common-root

I read the following in the book, *Kumar's Algebra, Page 144*:

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have common roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \ldots$, then the polynomial whose roots are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \ldots$ is given by $h(x) = af(x) + bg(x)$.

I don't understand what $a$ and $b$ are in the last line. Are they some suitable coefficients that must be used for the above condition to be true? Can they be computed algorithmically?

Comment: Can you give some broader context?  It's not clear what this statement is supposed to mean on its own.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are scalars i.e. $a,b\in\mathbb{F}$ for any field $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\cdots$

Comment: The word "the" is misleading here, since there are many polynomials whose roots are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\dots$. In particular, any polynomial of the form $af(x)+bg(x)$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary scalars has those roots (and possibly other roots as well). There are also polynomials not of this form which also have said roots.

Comment: @Rahul does that mean $a$ and $b$ can be any scalars? As in, they can be $1$ in all the cases.

Comment: Yes, if $f$ and $g$ are zero at $\alpha$ then $f+g$ is also zero at $\alpha$, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's written that way in your text-book, but I'd say that the way you wrote the statement is vague and very misleading.

First, the word "the" is inappropriate, because it implies that there is only one polynomial that has the same roots as $f$ and $g$, whereas in fact there are many. In particular, if $a$ and $b$ are **any** numbers whatsoever, then the polynomial $h = af+bg$ has the same roots as $f$ and $g$. If $f(\alpha)=0$ and $g(\alpha)=0$, then clearly $h(\alpha) = 0$, too, so all common roots of $f$ and $g$ are roots of $h$.